# Cannot find symbol compile error in for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm having a problem with my code here. I'm trying to find all multiples of 3 and 5 up to one thousand and add them all up, and at the end when I try to output the sum, java gives me a 'cannot find symbol' error. Can anybody figure out what's wrong here?

```
public class Problem1
    {
        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            //int sum1;
            //int sum2;
            int finalSum;

            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                if(i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    int sum;
                    sum += i;
                }
                else if(i % 5 == 0)
                {
                    int sum;
                    sum += i;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ignore the sum1, sum2, and finalSum declarations, that's from earlier code that was woefully overcomplicated.

Comment: Then omit them entirely from the question since they add nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Java has [*block scoping,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope_within_a_function) which means that the `sum` declared in between `{}`s (braces) is not visible outside. Declare `sum` **once,** outside of the `for` loop.

```
public class Problem1
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if(i % 3 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
            else if(i % 5 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I compile this I get 'variable sum may not have been initialized' on all lines where sum is called.

Comment: Indeed. You need to initialize it. **Learn to read, _really read,_ the compiler's error messages.** They are immensely useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can not declare `sum` in loop.Then it is local to that method.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're "creating" `sum` inside the `if` statements which limits their scope - they're created within the `if` blocks and destroyed at the next closing brace.

Get rid of those two `int sum;` lines inside the `if` blocks and put it at the top of the function (where the rather useless `finalSum` is). Or just *use* `finalSum` everywhere.

You can also combine the `if` conditions for shorter code:

```
public class Problem1
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int finalSum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            if((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0))
                finalSum += i;

        System.out.println(finalSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend removing the braces here. OP is clearly a beginner and this will just confuse things.

Comment: Matt, learn early, learn often :-) I find it much easier to read _without_ unnecessary punctuation, provided the indents are done correctly.

Comment: Meh, too easy to make a mistake later. Not worth it, particularly at this level.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined the variable sum inside the the if/else which limits the scope of the variable.`System.out.print()` statement is outside the scope of `sum` hence you are getting the error.

```
public class Problem1
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if(i % 3 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
            else if(i % 5 == 0)
            {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```